# Querying Firestore for items with timestamp before today

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In the new Cloud Firestore you can set a server timestamp on my message object using the following line during creation of the object:

```
showtime: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

This is useful for messages from any user as it does not rely in each users local clock.

The challenge I am having is in querying and setting the showtime field afterwards. What I want to do is look up any message that has a showtime that is early than 'now'. In my application many messages are pushed into the future. I only want the ones with a showtime before today to be returned and displayed.

Here is my query:

```
  var query = firebase.firestore()
                  .collection('messages')
                  .where('owner','==',userID)
                  .where('showtime','<',timenow)
                  .orderBy('showtime', 'desc')
                  .limit(25);
```

The challenge is that I do not know how to get the current time (on the server) to use in the query. There is a now() call on the type Timestamp in Firebase, but I am unsure how to call it AND I am not sure based on some other questions here whether the Firebase timestamp matches the Cloud Firestore timestamp!

So the question is: How do I set a variable called timenow to be the current time on the server and use it in a query to pull 25 messages before now? (in Javascript on the client and also extra credit for in a function on the server)

A quick follow on question is then how I update the showtime timestamp to be one week later than now?

Hope we have some Firebase / Cloud Firestore mavens on Stackoverflow!

** Choosing an answer below with the caveat of a feature request: A call in Firebase to the server to request a current timestamp so that the client code can work off one standard clock. **

Comment: I believe I can use 'new Date()' as the timenow value. I'm not sure if creating a new Date happens every time the query is updated? I then believe I can update a message's showtime to one week later by using toDate() on the showtime returned by firestore and then adding one week to it using date.getDate() + 7. I've done both in my code and it seems to work but I would like official confirmation. I also think that 'new Date()' gets the current date of the client so I most likely will need to get the current time from the server into this query instead to avoid client faking of the date.

Comment: Can this be done on the client to get the cloud firestore timestamp? const timestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right `serverTimestamp()` is exactly for getting a timestamp on the server and not relying on the users local clock. One thing to note is that generally sending a message and getting the timestamp from a users local clock is going to be okay as a message timestamp is not extremely time sensitive. Sure you would like to know when the message is sent but if it is within 1-2 seconds not a problem in most cases.

If you are doing a query on the client side your query should not be based on the server time it should be based on the client side. As it is a client query not a server query.

Here is a client query that you are after.

```
const currentTime = new Date();
const query = firebase.firestore()
                  .collection('messages')
                  .where('owner','==',userID)
                  .where('showtime','<',currentTime)
                  .orderBy('showtime', 'desc')
                  .limit(25);
```

This query will get 25 messages with a 'showtime' after the current time on the client.

Now if the messages need to be extremely time sensitive and you do absolutely need the messages to based off the server timestamp I recommend that instead of doing a query on the client like above you set up a cloud function api.
Have a look at the firebase docs for calling cloud functions directly if you haven't before.

Here is what you would want your cloud function to look like:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp()

exports.getUserMessages = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const uid = context.auth.uid;
    const firestore = admin.firestore();
    firestore.collection('messages')
             .where('owner', '==', uid)
             .where('showtime', '<', new Date())
             .orderBy('showtime', 'desc')
             .limit(25)
             .get()
             .then(snapshot => {
                return snapshot;
             });
});
```

This will get the messages based of the server timestamp. One thing to note is UNLESS you need this to be extremely time sensitive this is not a good idea. As this call has to do an extra unnecessary call every time you call it. Because you are doing a call to the cloud function and then you are doing a query to the firestore database.
I would recommend that instead of doing it based on the server time you do it based on client timestamp. 99 times out of 100 the time difference between client and server is not worth the extra double calls you are doing, especially when you think about scaling everything up when you get more users.

Hope that answered your question :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Its not the small difference between client time and server time that is my concern. Its that a client could set their clock to be two weeks ago or set it to two weeks forward and see posts from that time frame. In my app I have photo messages in the future that should not be seen until the actual future dates. So there isn't an option in the client side query to tell it to use the server timestamp for currentTime?

Comment: Okay I think you are getting a little bit confused here.
What client is able to set their clock forward or back?
This is a very odd case that you are talking about, there are many ways you can work around what you are explaining but the question what is the purpose and for what value. I think instead of trying to work around using firebase you should work around the clock jumping (which is not common if even possible these days). For example you could ping a timestamp server for the current time but thats hacky.

Comment: To answer your question if there is a way to use the server timestamp for the current time no there is not. You should use a cloud function instead. You can save with the server timestamp but you can query with the server timestamp as i showed with a cloud function.

Comment: I believe I can set my MacOS clock to any time and date. I believe I can do the same with my PC in Windows10. So then the Date would return the local PC or Mac clocks time and date which could be in 2014 or 2024. Then the query to the server would be wrong. Too bad there isnt a call in Firebase to get the server time/date to use in queries on the client side. That certainly would be the most efficient. I will look at functions and doing the message lookup on the server.

Comment: How about you do nothing, and if the odd user does say they can't see any data, THEN you figure out if it's their clock. It's just not a normal state to be in (like you said, a clock 2 weeks out), and chances are they're breaking a bunch of other apps anyway.

Comment: Users can gain advantages in many apps by shifting their local date and posting posts or comments. In building a robust app its key to have one definitive source of time and that should be the server and not the client. Building a well functioning app similar to SnapChat, Instagram or any modern social network requires this feature.

Comment: Seems like people are missing that his concern is security. So to the question of "who changes their clock"? The answer is... a nefarious user. Besides which the javascript itself could be edited. Never trust the client.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the excellent answer by Alex Dunlop, I was in a similar situation and it made sense once I realized that Firestore operates according to two design principles (or at least, that is my analysis)

1. The emphasis is on simple queries that stream live updates to you.  To enable this, queries are by design limited in complexity.  This takes load of the Firestore database server and allows it to stream (effectively re-run) queries fast.
   Because of the  limited query language and few 'server side' operators (`FieldValue` is one of the few), Google can optimize the queries mercilessly.
2. There are many more complex operations that developers require. Instead of implementing them in Firestore, developers are asked to spin up a cloud function which makes them responsible (in code and cost) for that additional complexity.

If you come from a conventional DB design like Postgres, the lack of query expressiveness and server-side operations is stunning.  If you think of the Firestore use case and the principles, it all makes sense.

Comment: It definitely makes sense. I spent many years with GAE and its had similar tradeoffs that I got used to and appreciated once I adjusted. WIth firebase it would be very helpful if the client could get the current server timestamp. It would be good to know that the firebase timestamp and the firestore one was in sync and compatible. A client call and some deeper materials on timestamp in the docs would not effect query performance and help immensely!

Answer (score 0):

Try Firestore security rules with data validation:

```
  match /messages/{msgId} {
    // optionally: request.time + someBuffer
    allow read: if request.time > resource.data.showtime;
  }
```

I don't think you want to trust the client (since you mentioned you want to block client access to future showtimes). Besides changing their clock, they could just edit the javascript.

A buffer might be necessary to not invalidate the query if there is some discrepancy between client provided `Date.now()` and Firestore rules `request.time`, sepecifically if the `request.time` happens to be earlier than client date, then the query would have documents falling outside valid range and fail.

Comment: I think this is great. The point you make that the JS could be hacked is well taken. I will likely attempt a move of the posting over to the server and then the querying as well.

Comment: Not sure of your entire use case, but if scalability and simplicity are important, doing as much as you can on the client saves you from having to maintain a separate resource. A callable cloud function might be minimal if you need it on server. But you lose power of security and data validation rules to handle authorization data validation for you. Structuring who can do what and when / with which data types is succinctly implemented in rules vs a server call.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the read timestamp on an empty snapshot seems to work:

```
const serverTime = (await db.collection('nonexistent').get()).readTime;
```

Agreed with one of the other comments that this extra call could be expensive, but this should work in cases where an accurate "not before" server time is important for correctness.